# ie 8 compatibality issues

Tags: cross-browser

I am having issues with ie 8 compatibility mode. I have some buttons that have images on them.  I also have some jquery validation on my page.  When I test the jquery validation with input that won't pass the validator, The image on the button disapears, the button extends to the end of the table row that it is held in, and text appears over the top of it.  This also occurs when I submit the page (in compatibility mode or not)... [image]

Also, not that there is a message above the Refresh button.  That message should only appear after a timeout javascript function has run its course.  And it does that when compatability mode is not on.  What is going on, and how can I change that.  Note, this is an ASP.net MVC2 site.  I know it all just writes HTML, but I thought that would be something nice to think about.

***UPDATE WITH code.***

```
    $(".datepicker1").datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        buttonImage: '<%=Url.Content("~/images/calendar.gif")%>',
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
```

The above would be the jquery code that has the button image code

```
    <div id="countdownDiv" style="display:none">
    <p><font color="#990000"><b>Sorry, This Data has expired. Please Refresh The page.</b></font></p>    
    <%
        Html.BeginForm("EditTemplate", "PatientACO", new { Template = PatID, popID = population, PopulationPatID = PopPatId, Enc = encounter });
        %><input type="submit" value="Refresh" id="test" /><%
      Html.EndForm();%>     
    </div>
```

The above would be the code segment that is always showing up.

Comment: [My Stack Overflow Answer did the trick for the DatePicker Button][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010347/datepicker-puts-text-on-button-instead-of-image/8011843#8011843

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="select" value="" />
<input type="image" name="submit" value="somePresident" src="president.gif" onclick="this.form.select.value = this.value" />
</form>
```

Taken from : http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-79035.html

Comment: Uh, what?  This is an asp.net MVC site.

Comment: It would help if you could show the code that is having the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010347/datepicker-puts-text-on-button-instead-of-image/8011843#8011843

That is the answer I came up with.  Since it is the comment sections of your answer, I will just check you up.  After all, you did give ti the old college try.